# Sum of numbers starting from 1 (python)

Tags: python

I started to learn Python and I am stucked in lesson. I need to create program, where you at first asked for insert digit (you insert for example "5") and result should be sum of digits starting from 1 up to this digit you inserted (in this example 1+2+3+4+5). I created a program which is listing numbers up to inserted digit, but I cannot finish it - to create sum of those digits. Here is my code:

```
print ("Insert the digit")
digit = int(input())
i = 0
while i < (digit):
    i = i + 1
    print (i)
```

Comment: summed = sum(range(digit+1))

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, you're not keeping a running total, you can however use a maths trick here, eg:

```
n = int(input('Enter digit: '))
print('Total sum is:', int(n*(n/2 + .5)))
```

This'll be far more efficient for larger `n`... so instead of building a generator and summing each at a time, you can use that formula to calculate in constant time any value of `n`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following:

```
i = 0
total = 0
while i < digit:
    i = i + 1 # can be i += 1
    total = total + i # can be total += i
print (total)
```

`range` function can also be used. You can read about this.

Comment: Best to not name the variable `sum` as you'll shadow the builtin... use  `total` or something instead...

Comment: that is the first answer that helps understanding the learning practise. Of course in python you would prefer `sum()`. I'd even prefer `total = (digit * (digit + 1) / 2)`, but that does not help OP any more than `sum()`

Answer (score 3):

you can use sum with range:

```
my_sum = sum(range(1,digit+1))
```

range will give you list of integers, syntax `range([start],stop)` ,it will ends always one less, see the demo below

demo:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

demo for `sum`:

```
>>> my_num = range(1,10)
>>> my_num
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> sum(my_num)
45
```

Comment: Since 0 is the default `start`, how about `sum(range(digit+1))`? 2 characters less!

Comment: yess it is , it did so Op understand about the range how it works

Comment: Note you need the +1 here, the sum of 1..10 inclusive is not 45 :p

Comment: yes its not My 1st post include `digit+1`, Its the demo of sum

Comment: @JonClements you are curious, its good, there must be some to review what someone has written

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
print ("Insert the digit")
digit = int(input())
print(sum(range(digit+1)))
```

Here `range` is a function which will list all the numbers from `0` to `digit` and `sum` will calculate the total of them

Answer (score 0):

A really pythonic way would be to do the following:

```
print ("Insert the digit")
digit = int(input())
i = 0
while i < (digit):
    i = i + 1
    print (i)
summed = sum(range(digit+1))
print(summed)
```

Note: You should not use the variable name sum because that is a reserved symbol (language intern)